# Swift - Dynamically set UITableView height in Xib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I try to set tableView height with dynamically in Xib. But all elements change dynamically in the xib view and I didn't reach "y" position of the last element before tableview.

I tried something like this but it didn't work.It shows on the top of mainView.

```
techTableView = mainView?.technicalTableView

self.techTableView?.frame = CGRect(
    x: 0,
    y: (self.techTableView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (mainView?.productInformation.bottomAnchor)!, constant: 25).constant)! ,
    width: self.view.frame.size.width,
    height: 35)
```

Comment: do you want to change height of table view or table view cell

Comment: tableView. I set the cell height.

Comment: you don't need to calculate size for cell each time use UITablviewAutomaticDimension that will calculate size of cell automatically just make sure you have give right constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use layout anchors to set the constraints instead of setting the frame. You can do something like this to set your tableview's constraints:

```
techTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    techTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    techTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    techTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    techTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks your advance dude.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to confusing, you are trying to set the table view frame by using anchors which is not the way of how it works. If you are aiming to do it via setup constraints then you should do it after adding the table view regardless of the value of its frame.

So, after after making sure that `techTableView` has been added to its superview (for instance: `view.addSubview(tableView)`) you would need to implement the following:

```
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// x axis:
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
// y axis:
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView?.productInformation.bottomAnchor, constant: 25.0).isActive = true
// width:
tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
// height:
tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35.0).isActive = true
```

At this point it should be displayed as expected, it has been handled by constraints, without the need of editing the frame (it is `CGRect.zero` by default).